# Grails AOP config exception

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, aop

I have a running grails app.
I upgraded the
  **springsecurity-core** from 1.2.7.3 to 2.0-RC2
  **springsecurity-acl** from 1.1.1 to 2.0-RC1
I added
  **springsecurity-oauth-provider** 1.0.5.1

And I get an exception during startup:

> Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.TypeSpecifyableTransactionProxyFactoryBean]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
>       at grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl.AclAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AclAutoProxyCreator.java:120)
>       ... 4 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
>       at net.sf.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
>       at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
>       at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
>       ... 5 more

(only last part of ex)

Comment: The workaround was to remove the "@PreAuhthorize" annotations from the code. These versions of springSecurity don't work well together from some reason.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You should add that as an answer and accept it as it makes it easier for others searching for this issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround was to remove the "@PreAuhthorize" annotations from the code. These versions of springSecurity don't work well together from some reason.